# OpenCV Python Linker Error

Tags: python, bash, opencv, heroku, cmake

I've been trying to install opencv on heroku to no avail. I've tried using heroku-anvil for the installation and am now trying to install opencv via the bash shell. First I installed cmake but then when I try to `make` opencv I inevitably get the following error:

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/cv2.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/cv2.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/python/CMakeFiles/opencv_python.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Here are the exact commands that I'm using:

```
# connect to bash shell

heroku run bash
cd /tmp

# Downloading and Installing cmake:

curl -s http://www.cmake.org/files/v2.8/cmake-2.8.12.1.tar.Z > cmake.tar.gz
tar zxf cmake.tar.gz
cd cmake-2.8.12.1/
./bootstrap
make
make install

# Download and Install OpenCV

curl -s https://s3.amazonaws.com/nerdglasses/opencv/OpenCV-2.4.2.tar.bz2 > opencv.tar.gz
tar xf opencv.tar.gz
cd OpenCV-2.4.2/
../cmake-2.8.12.1/bin/cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=NO -DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS="-fPIC" -DBUILD_DOCS=OFF -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DWITH_OPENEXR=OFF -DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=/app/.heroku -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/app/.heroku .
make # ERROR HERE
```

Anyone know how to fix this? Or if there is a better way to get opencv installed on heroku for a python web app?

Comment: Looks like there's a typo in your CMake command.  You seem to be missing a `-` at the front of the `DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS="-fPIC"` argument.

Comment: So should I try `DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS="--fPIC"`?

Comment: No - sorry - I meant `-DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS="-fPIC"`

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work and I got the same error :/

Comment: @PeterTseng This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21666240/installing-opencv-with-python-support-on-heroku?noredirect=1#comment32787688_21666240

Answer (score 2):

You need to reinstall python with shared and static way.

Firstly, download Python source file again.

and then..

```
./configure --enable-shared --enable-static
make
make install
```

In that way you might solve this problem out.

Here's the link that you might want to know.

[Installing OpenCV with python module on CentOS goes wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729495/installing-opencv-with-python-module-on-centos-goes-wrong/18733071#18733071)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem was faced by me on **Linux Mint 17.3 while installing Caffe and OpenCV python** linking

I didn't want to **reinstall python with --enable-shared** option since there were quite a few packages dependent on native python installation.

> On digging further found that two version's of python were installed in my system one in path **/usr/local/lib/python2.7** [built using python download from official website] and other in path **/usr/lib/python2.7** [installed with sudo apt-get install/ package manager]

The installation from official website is not Position Independent Code since enable shared was not provided during configuration of python. [PIC, compiler flag needed to be used].

Even after using -fPIC there was no luck and since **python at: /usr/local/lib/python2.7** is not useful for me, decided to remove it with below command

> **sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7**

Voila! It works now. This allowed python to be position independent code since it is based on package installation.